# ES query from Kibana 4 visualization?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a Kibana visualization (visState) that I wanna run in C#, is there any way to obtain the Elastic Search query from that visualization object? 
Is there any interface to get it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings -> Objects -> Visualizations.  Click the "edit" icon next to the one you want, and the Elasticsearch query will be displayed as "kibanaSavedObjectMeta.searchSourceJSON".

If you're using a saved searches, go to Settings -> Objects -> Searches.